# Convert only few Rows to Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose

I want to convert only 2 columns into rows in a table having 6 columns as below in SQL. Is it possible? I have tried `PIVOT`, but it isn't working as expected.

This is my table:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| ID |  Contact | DESC_ID | DESCRIPT |  VALUE   |
-------------------------------------------------
| 22 |  55555   |   1     | Name     |  Vijay   |   
| 22 |  55555   |   2     | Country  |  India   |   
| 22 |  55555   |   3     | State    |  Maha    |   
| 22 |  55555   |   4     | Location |  Mumbai  |   
| 22 |  55555   |   5     | Color    |  Brown   |   
-------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to create the below result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------                    
| ID |  Contact |   Name  | Country |   State  |  Location | Color |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 22 |  55555   |   Vijay | India   |    Maha  |   Mumbai  | Brown |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I query this. Is it possible?

Comment: Please, post your current attempt.

Comment: select ID,Contact,Country,State,Location,Color
  from 
 (
 select VALUE,DESCRIPT from table
 ) d 
 pivot
 (
 max(VALUE)
  for DESCRIPT in (ID,Contact,Country,State,Location,Color)
 ) piv

Comment: Mysql or sql-server - there is no pivot in mysql.

Comment: @Akhil.J pleas use the edit button to add your code to the question.

Comment: sql-server @P.Salmon

Comment: `ID` and `Contact` shouldn't be in your `PIVOT`. But like the others have said, **[edit]** your question and put your attempt in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create Table Table1 (ID int, Contact int, DESC_ID int, DESCRIPT varchar(100),  VALUE varchar(100));

insert into Table1(ID,Contact ,DESC_ID,DESCRIPT,VALUE)
values( 22 ,  55555   ,   1     , 'Name'     ,  'Vijay' )     
, (22 ,  55555   ,   2     , 'Country'  ,  'India'      )
,( 22 ,  55555   ,   3     , 'State'    ,  'Maha'       )
, (22 ,  55555   ,   4     , 'Location' ,  'Mumbai'     )
,( 22 ,  55555   ,   5     , 'Color'    ,  'Brown')
```

---

```
select * from 
( 
select ID,Contact,VALUE,DESCRIPT from table1 
) d 
pivot (
max(VALUE) for DESCRIPT in (Name,Country,State,Location,Color) 
) piv
```